# How can I retrieve data from ArrayCollection (Symfony)?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, entity, arraycollection

animals:

```
| id | name |
|----|------|
| 1  | cat  |
| 2  | dog  |
| 3  | frog |
```

category:

```
| id | name   |
|----|--------|
| 1  | green  |
| 2  | blue   |
| 3  | orange |
```

animals_category:

```
| animals_id | category_id |
|------------|-------------|
| 1          | 1           |
| 2          | 1           |
| 2          | 2           |
```

What I want to do is get the `categories` for `dog`:

```
green, blue
```

This is my approach:

Controller:

```
$id = '2';

$result = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('Animals:Category')->findByIdJoinedToCategory(['id'=>$id]);
```

Animals Repository:

```
   public function findByIdJoinedToCategory()
    {
        $query = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery(
                'SELECT a, b FROM Animals:Category a
                JOIN a.category b');
        try {
            return $query->getResult();
        } catch (\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

But I get an error message:

> Unknown Entity namespace alias 'Animals'.

entity `Animals`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\AnimalsRepository")
*/
class Animals
{
  /**
  * @ORM\Id()
  * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
  * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
  */
  private $id;


  /**
  * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
  */

  private $name;


  /**
  * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category")
  * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category", referencedColumnName="id")
  */
  private $category;




  public function getId(): ?int
  {
    return $this->id;
  }


  public function getName()
  {
    return $this->name;
  }

  public function setName($name)
  {
    $this->name = $name;
  }


  public function getCategory()
  {
    return $this->category;
  }

  public function setCategory($category): self
  {
    $this->category = $category;

    return $this;
  }

  public function addCategory(Category $category): self
  {
    $this->category[] = $category;

    return $this;
  }

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->category = new ArrayCollection();
  }
}
```

Comment: can you add your entity table name please?

Comment: @hoover_D sorry,  `Animals` is the entity name

Comment: You have to be placed in Animals repository to get them or do a join..

Comment: @hoover_D Yes, sorry, I did a mistake in my question. Now it is correct

Comment: can you just post your Entity Animals.php please?

Comment: @hoover_D green and blue are actually the categories for dog. For cat it is only green

Comment: @hoover_D I added the entity

Comment: Which version of Symfony do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no `Animals:Category` entity. You have entities `Animals` and `Category`.

The correct answer depends if you're using Symfony 3 or 4, because Symfony 3 uses entity aliases (namespacing with `:` notation which you're trying ot use), while Symfony 4  prefers full qualified namespace (`\App\Entity\Animals`).

So, first mistake is in line where you're trying to get repository:

```
getRepository('Animals:Category')
```

And the second in `findByIdJoinedToCategory()` in DQL query :

```
'SELECT a, b FROM Animals:Category a
JOIN a.category b'
```

Now solutions:

**Symfony 3**

Since it looks you don't have any bundles (I guess it's Symfony 4 but whatever), you don't have any entity namespace alias, so you should simply use its name.

```
getRepository('Animals')
```

Now, I assume, that with `a` you want to reference `Animals` entity/table, so it should be

```
'SELECT a, b FROM Animals a
JOIN a.category b'
```

**Symfony 4**

If you use Symfony 4, then use should use entity FQNS as entity name (`App\Entity\Animals`).

So it would be

```
getRepository('\App\Entity\Animals')
```

or

```
getRepository(\App\Entity\Animals::class)
```

to get repository. The second one is better, because it will be easier to refactor when needed (IDE will be able to find usage of class).

And in query it would be

```
'SELECT a, b FROM App\Entity\Animals a
JOIN a.category b'
```

or if you would like to avoid using hardcoded string class names:

```
'SELECT a, b FROM ' . \App\Entity\Animals:class . ' a
JOIN a.category b'
```

Comment: Thank you for the very good and detailed answer. I will test it out immediately. I have Symfony 4. So just one question. In my controller, I write then: `$result = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Animals::class)->findByIdJoinedToCategory(['id'=>$id]);`?

Comment: Actually I've just noticed, that you have also another issue. Method `findByIdJoinedToCategory()` method does not take any argument. So you will have to improve that too. It should expect `$id` parameter, then you should use it inside method to do what you want.

Comment: If I test your code and dump `result` then I get an array with all animals `cat, dog, frog`

Comment: That's because, as I wrote in previous comment,  you don't really utilize `$id` parameter to filter the query.

Comment: yes, Jarla, check my answer bellow with your id parameter and check if it works please